# Getting NaN in a JS function handling array contents

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have many blogposts loaded into an object/array, and I'm trying to calculate their performance based on their likes/dislikes ratio. But I'm getting NaN in the last step of the process.

```
function calcularRendimiento(){
  for(i = 0; i < recetas.length; i++){
    let likes = parseInt(recetas[i].likes); //getting this data properly
    let dislikes = parseInt(recetas[i].dislikes) //getting this data properly
    recetas[i].rendimiento = likes * 100 / (likes + dislikes);
    console.log(recetas[i].rendimiento); //NaN
  }
}
```

Any ideas?

EDIT: This is the class:

```
class Receta
{
  constructor(id,autor,titulo,foto,tiempo,metodo,likes,dislikes,rendimiento)
  {
      this.id = id;
      this.autor = autor;
      this.titulo = titulo;
      this.foto = foto;
      this.tiempo = tiempo;
      this.metodo = metodo;
      this.likes = likes;
      this.dislikes = dislikes;
      this.rendimiento = rendimiento;
  }
}
```

This is (part of) the preload:

```
function precargaRecetas() {
  nuevaReceta(1, 'chef', 'Torta frita', 'tortas_fritas.jpg', 120, 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Mauris efficitur augue vel elit lobortis, sed ultricies velit venenatis. Ut vel molestie sed.',0,0);
  nuevaReceta(2, "jluppi", "Hamburguesas Rellenas", 'hamburguesa-rellena.jpg', 180, 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Mauris efficitur augue vel elit lobortis, sed ultricies velit venenatis. Ut vel molestie sed.',0,0);
  nuevaReceta(3, "chef", "Pastel de Papa y Hongos", 'pastel-papas-hongos.jpg', 120, 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Mauris efficitur augue vel elit lobortis, sed ultricies velit venenatis. Ut vel molestie sed.',0,0);
  nuevaReceta(4, "mlopez", "Galletas de avena y pasas", 'galletas-avena-pasas.jpg', 90, 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Mauris efficitur augue vel elit lobortis, sed ultricies velit venenatis. Ut vel molestie sed.',0,0);
}
```

This function is called by the preload:

```
function nuevaReceta(id, autor, titulo, foto, tiempo, metodo, likes, dislikes) {
  let exito = false;
  if (validacionReceta(id, autor, titulo, foto, tiempo, metodo, likes, dislikes)) {
    let receta = new Receta(id, autor, titulo, foto, tiempo, metodo, likes, dislikes);
    recetas.push(receta);
    exito = true;
  }
  return exito;
}
```

And this validator is called by the function

```
function validacionReceta(id, autor, titulo, foto, tiempo, metodo, likes, dislikes) {
  let datosValidados = true;
  if (titulo.length = 0 || titulo.length > 50) {
    datosValidados = false;
  }
  if (foto = null) {
    datosValidados = false;
  }
  if (tiempo = 0 || tiempo > 1440) {
    datosValidados = false;
  }
  if (metodo.length = 0 || metodo.length > 150) {
    datosValidados = false;
  }
  return datosValidados;
}
```

Comment: I don't think this is the issue, but you should really be doing `parseInt(recetas[i].likes, 10)`.

Comment: add your sample code

Comment: Can you please give an example of the values involved, as if `likes` and `dislikes` really do have valid integer values then the code will work correctly.

Comment: edited with further code.

Comment: All your likes and dislikes are `0`. `likes * 100 / (likes + dislikes)` -> `0 * 100 / (0 + 0)` -> `0 / 0` -> `NaN`. You might want to build in a check for when `likes + dislikes` end up being `0`. [You can't devide by zero](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Division_by_zero).

Comment: Nice, I'm gonna try that. Thanks.

Comment: I changed several likes/dislikes on the preload and added a condition to set performance to 0 when the sum between likes/dislikes = 0. It worked like a charm. Thanks Ivar.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```js
function calcularRendimiento(){
  for(i = 0; i < recetas.length; i++){
    let likes = parseInt(recetas[i].likes); //getting this data properly

    if(!(likes > 0)) continue;

    let dislikes = parseInt(recetas[i].dislikes) //getting this data properly

    if(!(dislikes > 0)) continue;   

    recetas[i].rendimiento = likes * 100 / (likes + dislikes);
    console.log(recetas[i].rendimiento); //NaN
  }
}
```

To avoid divide by `0` errors, as in your sample data all the likes and dislikes appear to be `0`.